# Use counter collection in node.js to increment ID field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I wanted to set up an auto incrementing ID on one of my collections (_id is too long). To do this I created a 'counters' collection as suggested in a number of posts including Mongos official site (below):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Counter', {
    _id: String,
    sequence_value: Number
});
```

I then inserted one counter with a seq value. Below is a function which is called when creating a new Item. The Logic to add the new item works and the query to get the counter value works to the extent that `console.log(data.sequence_value);` returns the sequence_value.

But I cannot then apply the sequence_value to the item creation logic by doing something like the following:

```
 module.exports.newitem = function(req, res){            
            var nextId = Counter.findByIdAndUpdate(
                {_id: 'productid'},
                { $inc: { incr: 1 } },
                function (err, data) {
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err.stack || err.message)
                    } else{
                        console.log("successful")
                    }
                    console.log(data.sequence_value);
                    return data.sequence_value
                });

        var item = new Item();
        item.itemId = nextId;

        // Save the item that has been sent.
        item.save();

        // If adding the user is successful. Send back the user.
        res.json(req.body);
    };
```

The current disjointed version of the logic is below:

```
module.exports.newitem = function(req, res){

        Counter.findByIdAndUpdate(
            {_id: 'productid'},
            { $inc: { incr: 1 } },
            function (err, data) {
                if(err){
                    console.log(err.stack || err.message)
                } else{
                    console.log("successful")
                }
                console.log(data.sequence_value);
            });



    var item = new Item();
    item.itemId = "2000";

    // Save the item that has been sent.
    item.save();

    // If adding the user is successful. Send back the user.
    res.json(req.body);
};
```

Hopefully the above makes sense. Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findByIdAndUpdate` is an an asynchronous function.  You should put your logic depending on its callback inside the callback itself, like so:

```
        var nextId = Counter.findByIdAndUpdate(
            {_id: 'productid'},
            { $inc: { incr: 1 } },
            function (err, data) {
                if(err){
                    console.log(err.stack || err.message)
                } else{
                    console.log("successful")
                }
                console.log(data.sequence_value);

                var item = new Item();
                item.itemId = data.sequence_value;

                 // Save the item that has been sent.
                item.save();  // arguably, your response would come in the .save() callback, if you care about whether that was successful or not. 

               // If adding the user is successful. Send back the user.
                res.json(req.body);
            });


};
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, that did the trick. I will need to go do some reading on the async side of things.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would put what I ended up with using Paul's answer.

```
module.exports.newitem = function(req, res){

        Counter.findByIdAndUpdate(
            {_id: 'productid'},
            { $inc: { sequence_value: 1 } },
            { "upsert": true },
            function (err, data) {
                if(err){
                    console.log(err.stack || err.message)
                } else{
                    var item = new Item();
                    item.itemId = data.sequence_value;
                    ...

                    // Save the item that has been sent.
                    item.save();

                    // If adding the user is successful. Send back the user.
                    res.json(req.body);
                    console.log("successful")
                }
            });
};
```